# Full page refresh in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I need experts advice. i am going to develop a website which will contains google adsense and other ads. please suggest me that should i go for classic web application or i can go with MVC2/MVC3. because i would require complete page refresh (because of adsense and other advertisement). My site will contain lots of videos and images and will get around 200000 - 300000 hits per day.

Please suggest because i am willing to develop it in MVC2/MVC3. but i am not sure which type( mvc or classic) will provide me more benefit to get full page refresh. and also please suggest that i should go for MVC2 or MVC3

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for ASP.NET MVC 3. You can do whatever refreshes you like (full, partial, ...) and yuo will probably even have more control over them compared to classic WebForms (but that might be a little subjective and only personal opinion).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend MVC3 because the Syntax of the Razor ViewEngine is much more readable than MVC2's ASPX (you could use ASPX in MVC3 anyway).

ASP.NET WebForms won't give you the same amount of easy control over your returned html what makes tracking pretty difficult.